# In a MERN + REDUX app if a user clears the local storage (token) after he is logged in will he still be able to access the application?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

If a user is logged in and his credentials along with JWT token are stored in the local storage. Now if the user after logging in clear the local storage will he be able to still use the application ?
I'm redux to perform all these operations of storing the user creds and token.

Comment: If the app uses the credentials from the redux store to authenticate calls to an API, they would still be logged in for the current browser session. Credentials are usually only put in local storage to persist them between browser sessions. Because the redux store, as it exists in memory during runtime, is gone if you close the browser tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

Hey depends where you save the token for the sample i you have the token in the cookie I think no.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).